# Can Mid 2010 Apple Macbook Pro 15" NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M graphics processor be Upgraded?

Tags: upgrade

Can a NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M graphics processor with 256MB of GDDR3 memory on 2.4GHz and 2.53GHz configurations; or 512MB of GDDR3 memory on 2.66GHz configuration on a mid 2010 macbook pro be upgraded?

Answer (score 1):

The GPU is soldered to the logic board, and is therefore not replaceable.

You may want to explore external graphic cards. eGPU.